# Associativity of (co)Products

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I have proved the following:

> Let $I=\bigcup _{k\in K}J_k$ be a partition of a set $I$. Consider of famility $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of objects in a category $\mathsf C$. When all the products involved exist, the following isomorphism holds: $$\coprod_{i\in I}A_i \cong \coprod _{k\in K} \left( \coprod _{j\in J_k}A_j \right) $$

Now I want to *formally* prove that $$\coprod _{i\in I,j\in J}A_{i,j}\cong \coprod _{i\in I} \left( \coprod _{j\in J}A_{i,j} \right) $$ But I don't see how. I think it should follow as a special case of what I proved but I can't figure out exactly how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $I' = I × J$ and $K = I$. Then $I' = \bigcup_{k∈K} J_k$ is a partition of $I'$ where $J_k = \{k\}×J$. Then use what you’ve proved on $\coprod_{(i,j) ∈ I×J} A_{i,j} = \coprod_{i' ∈ I'} A_{i'}$.

Comment: Ah, so simple! I kept trying to use $I^{\prime}=I\coprod J$ and taking the partition to be the injections $\iota I, \iota J$.

Comment: @Exterior I know that feeling! : D

Comment: Small question: technically, we get $\coprod _{{i^ \prime} \in I^{\prime}} A_{i^{\prime}} \cong \coprod _{k\in K=I} \left( \coprod _{j\in \left\{ k \right\} \times J}A_j \right)$ but we want $\coprod _{j\in \left\{ k \right\} \times J}A_j$ to be replaced by $\coprod _{j\in J} A_j$. How should I formally justify this? Of course both of them are coproducts, but I don't see why this is enough (formally).

Comment: You want $\coprod_{j∈ J_k} A_j$ to be replaced by $\coprod_{j ∈ J} A_{k,j}$, I guess. But there’s a bijection $J \cong J_k$ making the indexings $J → \mathcal C,~j ↦ A_{k,j}$ and $J_k → \mathcal C,~j ↦ A_j$ (over which the colimits are taken) commute. So I guess, you have to formally prove that $\lim D = \lim (D∘σ)$ for a diagram $D \colon J → \mathcal C$ and an isomorphism of categories $σ \colon J' → J$?

Comment: Uh, that sucks :(

Comment: @Exterior If you want to work very formally you have to work more and you really have to work the definitions *a lot*. But at this level, for most people it’s okay to just state these little assertions without proving them. See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/639506/42242). (I have great sympathies for you because I have a similar *need* for formalism as well.)

Comment: Haha that question had some nice answers. I appreciate both your sympathy and your great answers! I think for me, trying to make sure these things work out perfectly on the most formal level is an attempt to understand the definitions better. I got tired after proving the general proposition (which was left as an exercise in Borceux), that's why I asked here.

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent proving $\lim D = \lim (D∘\sigma)$ and in particular using limits? I couldn't think of an "elementary" proof..